# Mixing LED and regular light bulbs

Tags: dodge, lights, led

I have a 2004 Dodge Sprinter that currently has incandescent bulbs all around. I want to replace some of the lights with brighter LED bulbs. Can I mix LED and incandescent bulbs? Does this change the load resistor setup that I need to use? Or do I have to get a full set of LED lights all around? I was thinking of just replacing the head lights, tail lights, and lower brake lights with LEDs and leaving the rest (parking, side markers, turn signals, center brake light) incandescent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mix of both yes. Just remember that if they are for indicators to either add inline resistors to the led bulbs as these draw much less energy than the incandescent bulbs and will flash too fast or not at all. Or instead of resistors change the relay. Hope this helps